# How to redirect Laravel route to relavant page using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

working with Laravel 8 project and I am using scrolling navigation for my each pages and I have following contact page showing sucessful message when submitting contact form data as well.
Contact Controller

```
$this->validate($request,[
            'name' => 'required|max:100',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'telephone' => 'required',
        ]);

        $user = new User;

        $user->name = $request->input('name');
        $user->email = $request->input('email');
        $user->telephone = $request->input('telephone');
        $user->message = $request->input('message');
        
        $user->save();

        $verifyUser = VerifyUser::create([
            'user_id' => $user->id,
            'token' => Str::random(40)
        ]);

        Mail::to($user->email)->send(new VerifyMail($user));

       return redirect()->back()->with('info','We sent you an activation code. Check your email and click on the link to verify');
```

my javascript navigation script like this

```
<a href="#contact">contact</a>
<a href="#packages">packages</a>
    <a href="#reviews">reviews</a>
    <a href="#contact">contact</a> //contact page
    <a href="#video">video</a>
```

but I have my navigation using jquery and as the result of this after redirect contact submitting it is redirecting to the top of the home page. but I need scroll contact segment after submitting contact form. then how could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can redirect to a "route()" and append the hash needed or add as parameter

```
return redirect()->route('route_name', ['#contact'])->with('info','We sent you an activation code. Check your email and click on the link to verify');
```